# It is possible to have a mapping with dynamic arrays as a value?

Tags: evm, mapping

I would to achieve a dynamic generic storage, and I would to create something like this

```
contract GenericStorage{
   mapping (string => int[]) db;
   
   function createList(string memory key) public {
       db[key] = int[]; //this is dynamic array with flexible length, push, pop, etc
   }
}
```

This gives me following error:

```
Type type(int256[] memory) is not implicitly convertible to expected type int256[] storage ref.
```

Is there a library / workaround to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

It does work.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: ISC

pragma solidity 0.8.4;

contract A {
    mapping (string => uint256[]) public counter;
    
    function foo(string memory key, uint256 n) public {
        uint256[] memory data = new uint256[](n);
        for (uint256 i=0; i<n; i += 1) {
            data[i] = 1+i;
        }
        counter[key] = data;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! But here you are using a fixed-length array (n sized, with n provided to function foo).

Comment: @Andrean Sorry, I tried to copy from your question but the code has syntax errors. Do you have a example code that shows the exact error?